# Mathematically balancing chemical equation yields weird results

Tags: stoichiometry

I found this equation while testing my equation balancer:
$$
\ce{a C7H6O3 + b C4H6O3 -> c C9H8O4 + d C2H4O2}
$$

Obviously, $a = b = c = d = 1$ is a solution. However, if we were to bring in some maths:

$
\begin{cases}
7 a + 4b &= 9c + 2d\\
6a + 6b &= 8c + 4d\\
3a + 3b &= 4c + 2d\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
a &= \frac{11}{9}\alpha - \frac{2}{9}\beta\\
b &= \frac{1}{9}\alpha + \frac{8}{9}\beta\\
c &= \alpha\\
d &= \beta\\
\end{cases}
$

This leaves us with many ways of balancing the equation:

- when $\alpha = 1, \beta = 1$, $a = b = c = d = 1$; $\ce{C7H6O3 + C4H6O3 -> C9H8O4 + C2H4O2}$
- when $\alpha = 1, \beta = 2$, $\begin{cases}
  a &= 7\\
  b &= 17\\
  c &= 9\\
  d &= 18\\
  \end{cases}$; $\ce{7 C7H6O3 + 17 C4H6O3 -> 9 C9H8O4 + 18 C2H4O2}$
- when $\alpha = 2, \beta = 1$...

From what I know, this happens when the equation consists of 2 or more independent equations (as is the case here: [More than one way of balancing a chemical equation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64202/more-than-one-way-of-balancing-a-chemical-equation)). However, here the two equations are:

$$
\ce{11 C7H6O3 + C4H6O3 -> 9 C9H8O4}
\\
\ce{-2 C7H6O3 + 8 C4H6O3 -> 9 C2H4O2}
$$

What is concerning here is that the second equation has a negative stoichiometric coefficient. My question is, is a negative coefficient acceptable in an equation, and in this case which is the correct way to balance the equation?

Comment: Your equation was already balanced, so why would you try to get other solution?

Comment: @Mithoron I guess I am being more a mathematician than a chemist here, but clearly there are other solutions, which makes me wonder if they too are valid solutions.

Comment: There is nothing special about a negative coefficient. If you prefer not to have it, transfer that term to the other side.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ohh, I didn't think about that! So a negative coefficient in the reactants is equivalent to a positive coefficient in the products, right? Would you like to elaborate in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You may answer your question yourself.

Comment: @Jingjie YANG you are correct, negative coefficients just flip to be positive on the other side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Ivan Neretin and @Tyberius pointed out, the negative coefficient of a reactant can be flipped to be positive by moving the reactant to the products' side.

So, in my case, the equations become
$$\begin{align}
\ce{11C7H6O3 + C4H6O3 &-> 9C9H8O4}\\
\ce{8C4H6O3 &-> 2C7H6O3 + 9C2H4O2}
\end{align}$$

Now, since the original equation $\ce{C7H6O3 + C4H6O3 -> C9H8O4 + C2H4O2}$ consists of 2 independent equations which can be separately balanced and combined in an arbitrary proportion. See  [More than one way of balancing a chemical equation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64202/more-than-one-way-of-balancing-a-chemical-equation) for a more detailed explanation.