# Two different answers obtained by balancing this chemical equation!! Somehow

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, stoichiometry

This is the concerned equation:

$\ce{ XeF4 +  H2O ->  Xe + XeO3 + HF + O2}$

This can be balanced as

$\ce{6 XeF4 + 12 H2O -> 4 Xe + 2 XeO3 + 24HF + 3 O2}$

or

$\ce{5 XeF4 + 10H2O ->3 Xe + 2 XeO3 + 20 HF + 2 O2}$

Former is what found in [this](http://ncertbooks.prashanthellina.com/class_12.Chemistry.ChemistryI/7.pdf) book.  NCERT chemistry part one, the textbook for class 12th. Chapter 7 page number 205 (b) Xenon Oxygen compounds, at the top.

while the latter is the one I come up while I was messing the equation. Something is wrong here. But what?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64202/more-than-one-way-of-balancing-a-chemical-equation/64233#64233

Comment: Even more related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58069/

Comment: I like how the title sounds like "somehow duplicate"